# R_average along the rows of an array

Tags: arrays, r, mean

I have an array with following dimensions

```
myarray<-array(dim=c(20,12,5))
```

I want to get the mean of second row of each slices of the array, so in total there should be 5 values. I know I can do this by simply writing something like

```
mean(myarray[2,,1])
```

for each slices of the array. But I want to do it using ´apply´ function to return a vector of 5 mean values. I am new user of R. Can anybody help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here the apply is not needed you can use colMeans instead:

```
colMeans(myarray[2,,])
```

hth

Answer (score 3):

You *may* `apply` a function on the 3rd dimension of an array as well:

```
myarray <- array(runif(20*12*5), dim=c(20,12,5))
apply(myarray, 3, mean)
## [1] 0.4891501 0.5431329 0.5253883 0.5413796 0.5236548
```

If this has to be the 2nd row, then try:

```
apply(myarray[2,,], 2, mean)
## [1] 0.6633603 0.5042602 0.6347945 0.6094396 0.4131304
```